# What is happening in this npm install of yo (yeoman)

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to better understand how npm works. In particular, I have noticed the following output on my (Windows) command line when I run `npm install -g yo`:

```
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/debuglog/0.0.2
npm http GET https://github.com/Filirom1/nopt/tarball/master#pull-request-in-pro
gress
```

I understand that the debuglog module is being pulled from the npm registry, but what is happening with nopt? Why is it going to the github repo?

Additionally, where is the config that tells npm to go to the github repo and download the tarball from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the package.json file of a module, for your dependency, you can specify github url as dependency (instead of the version).

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "package-name": "<github-tarbal-url>"
}
```

For e.g., the findup package has nopt package as a dependency and has put it's github url against the dependency name - 
https://github.com/Filirom1/findup/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Oh cool! How did you know that the reference to that URL was inside the findup package.json?